# In RAD Studio XE2, how do I properly add an image file to the project w/o making it a project resource?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2

I have several diagrams/plots/etc as an important part of the project documentation. As they are important I'd like to have them immediately available from the **Project Manager**. But, IDE insists what they are resources and keeps adding them to **Resources and Images** dialog (also binds them to the resulting executable, effectively making linking time humongous). So, how do I use an image as a part of project, but not as project resource without hacking into `.dproj` file?

Comment: What about using the [`Deployment Manager`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Deployment_Manager)?

Comment: If you don't want the images linked into the exe, then why add them to the project at all?

Comment: I'm with David. My other project files such as HelpAndManual documentation source are in a folder structure alongside the Delphi source.

Comment: So do I. It is a misuse of the Delphi Project File, because the meaning of the Delphi Project File is to keep everything together related to the Application to build the executable. Not more, not less